# How much money would I need to earn in Dubai?

Tags: uae

I got contacted by a recruiter offering me a job at the Emirates Airlines (as a software developer) in Dubai with a monthly salary USD 5000 - 6000. Is it enough to live there and potentionally generate some savings? I don't have high standards, but I want to relocate with my family (if at all): 4 kids + wife who won't be working while we're in Dubai.

FYI, I'm an EU citizen.

Comment: What's acceptable for you may well be unacceptable for others, or the reverse. Thus, the answer will depend upon opinion, not upon facts or references or citations. I voted to close as "opinion-based."

Comment: At least someone can tell me what's a typical salary for an IT developer in Dubai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search shows [The average salary for a developer in Dubai](https://ae.indeed.com/career/developer/salaries/Dubai) is AED 6,365 per month, around US$1730 at today’s exchange rate.

[Numbeo](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/Dubai) cost of living indicators in Dubai are:

- A family of four estimated monthly costs are 3,712.9$ (13,634.9AED) without rent.
- A single person estimated monthly costs are 1,067.8$ (3,921.1AED) without rent.

Numbeo’s rental cost indicators range from $1175 to $3929 depending on area/size of rental.

Input the city where you live to see an indicative cost of living comparison between your current location and Dubai.